# Trouble with jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am getting different errors in FF, Chrome and IE, but it all boils down there is an error with the data in $.ajax.  Following is the code.  Please go easy if I made a dumb mistake.  I have spent hours researching this and can't figure it out.  Any help appreciated.

**Edited to include the error messages**

FF Error message: `NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument`

Chrome Error message:`Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

IE9 Error message: `SCRIPT65535: Argument not optional`

Here is the code

```
    mc.mc_data.click_tracking = [];
var sequence = 0;
var send_it;
// the container click event will record even extraneous clicks.  need to change it to extending the jquery on click handler
$('#container').on('click', function(event) {
    logClicks(event);
    if(!send_it){
        sendIt()
    }
    sequence++;
});


function sendIt(){
    var tracking = mc.mc_data.click_tracking;
    var url = '/ajax/click_trackin';
    console.log("clicks["+sequence+"] "+$.isArray(tracking));
    $.each(tracking, function(i,v){
        console.log(i + v.innerText + " - " + v.sequence);
    });
    send_it = window.setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {
                clicks:tracking
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                if(response.result.length<1){
                    console.log(response+ ': no response');
                }else{
                    console.log(response);
                    tracking = mc.mc_data.click_tracks = [];                            
                }
                mc.mc_data.click_tracks = [];
                clearInterval(send_it);
                sendIt();
            },
            error: function(a, b, c){
                console.log(a+" - " + b+" - "+ c);
                clearInterval(send_it);
            }
        });

    }, 5000);
}


//

function logClicks(e){
    var temp_click = {
      'business_id':window.mc.businessid, 
      'userid':window.mc.userid, 
      'timestamp':e.timeStamp,
      'leg':window.mc.currentLeg,
      'workflow': 'dummy data',
      'sequence': sequence,
      'type':e.type, 
      'target':e.target, 
      'parent': e.target.parentElement,
      'id':e.target.id, 
      'class':e.className,
      'innerText': $(e.target).text()
    }
    mc.mc_data.click_tracking.push(temp_click);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `data`, you are meant to pass an object which will later be converted into a query string. You are passing the variable `tracking`, which contains stuff like `e.target.parentElement`, which is a DOM Node, containing really a lot of further properties (like other DOM Nodes!). The error can originate from either having problems converting a DOM Node into a query string, or creating a way too long query string. It would not make much sense to send a DOM Node to the server anyways.

Only send what is necessary and can be reasonably converted to a query string.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I actually accidentally left the processData:false in the code I pasted accidentally.  It was a desperation try Imade just before posting here.  I have edited the original post to reflect the absence of processData:false.

Comment: @Keith It would be useful if you posted the error messages, which line the problem is in, or created a demo that we could try and debug. Whichever you choose, edit it into your question.

Comment: @Keith Which line do they refer to? Also, it seems like you would want to use `setTimeout` here, not `setInterval`.

Comment: They all point to line 4 in jQuery, but I am inferring they refer to `            data: {
                clicks:tracking
            },` - specifically the tracking variable, which is an array of objects

Comment: @Keith Oh I see now. If you set `data`, it will try to create a query string out of your object. It seems like `tracking` includes stuff like `e.target` and `e.target.parentElement`, which are special DOM objects and I guess jQuery is having a hard time creating a query string from them. Only put things inside `data` that can be reasonably converted into a query string.

Comment: Aha!  Thank you.  Yes, as soon as I replaced those with strings it worked!